# Drupal 7: Why only guests can submit a webform api form?

Tags: forms, drupal, roles

I use Drupal 7 and the webform API. I made a contact form which works pretty well when you enter the site as a guest, but for authenticated users it doesn't store the data after submitting without having a protocol failure in reports.

[image]

Of course I activated this form to be used by all roles in the form settings. I don't use any node permission module. Does somebody have a clue what I could do or try to get rid of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Actually there is none in the report settings. That's why I wonder :(

Comment: Did you activate the module dblog to see the error logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrote the default template in your theme for the contact form. But had the following line at the end commented out: `print drupal_render_children($form);`. This prevents the creation of some hidden form fields including the CSRF token. For security reasons logged in users can't submit forms without token.